# Addressable LEDs vs Multiplexing for a Matrix

Tags: rgb-led, multiplexer

I would like to building a 8x64 RGB Matrix and connect it to my Arduino.
As this form factor does not really exist I would need to build one myself but now I am wondering if I should use addressable LEDs like WS2813 or APA107 and use FastLED or rather use 'dumb' LEDs and just multi-/charlieplex them using a MAX7221 or comparable chip.

What are some pros and cons I should consider with each one? I read that to many WS2813 can make problems but APA107 seem to fix that. But on the other hand most bigger matrices just use multiplexing........

Comment: the WS2813 would require way less hardware for interfacing

Comment: Cost would be one factor. Durability is another. When one of the addressable leds fail, all the leds after it would fail too (though the WS2813 has a BIN pin to "fix" that). I heard they aren't as reliable as dumb leds with separate drivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smart RGB LEDs will be brighter. Each device has its own control chip that controls the 256 PWM level for each of the 3 LEDs. So for an 8x64 array, you send in 3 bytes/device, 8x64x3 = 1535 btyes, pause a few microseconds, and the array updates itself.

Going the multiplexing route, you would do something like have 64x3 = 192 anode drivers (or up to 192, if not all are LEDs are lit up) to enable the LEDs across the display, and then 8 common cathode drivers to turn on each row one at a time for 1/30 to 1/24 of a second for minimal flicker. So 192 LEDs, 20mA each, the common cathode needs to be able to sink 3.84A

On the otherhand, 8x64 LEDs, each needing up to 60mA at full on, = 30.72A.

Comment: You are assuming common cathode leds here. There are also common anode RGB leds. Secondly 64*3 x 8 isn't the only configuration possible. You could wire it as if it's a 32*3 x 16 matrix etc. The latter would require fewer chips, but would be less bright.

Comment: Any kind of multiplexing will be less bright. Common anode, common cathode, turned in rows, turned on as columns.